# Visual Studio 2013 and 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have problem with intellisence in visual studio 2013 and 2015 the problem is that some built in functions are not shown picking up and when I type manually then it gives error for example when I use entity framework the I use SaveChangesAsync() but it does not showing when I type it it gives error and also more functions are also not available , it also not giving DeleteOnSubmit(), and others functions like these

Comment: First of all - those methods are not available in every Entity Framework version. Second -  here, have some commas and dots: "....,,,,,", and learn to use them. Third - I really doubt this is problem with VS version. Did it work under older version, but stopped working after moving to new version? Fourth: What error do you get?

Comment: it create a common error like as common function which is not defined and we are calling it so it asks for creating Stub mehtod

Comment: Then it means there is no such function. Check version of Entity Framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because there is a reference to the wrong (older?) version of the dll in your web.config/app.config. Check your entity framework version numbers under references and compare them with those in your web.config.

In some projects, like MVC with areas, you will have multiple web.configs that will need checking

Comment: which thing have to be changed ? in mvc and applications files web.config and app.config respectively

Comment: Sorry, I missed this one. You need to make sure they match. I would probably update your web.config to match the version in your references.